# Capture invisible (i.e.locked) virtual desktop

Tags: security, screenshot, desktop

For test automation I'd like to capture a virtual desktop which is not visible. It is not even accessible, as a secure desktop is shown.

I know it is possible to hook into the composite manager ("dwm") to capture each and every window on that desktop. And I kmow it is possible to send events to windows on that desktop. (I know that because otherwise the test tools wouldn't work)

Before I start to re-implement the composite manager: Is it possible to get the DesktopWindow from dwm, and if so  how Do I force dwm to do its job even if a secure desktop is shown?

If I have to bite the bullet and need to implemrnt compositing myself, what is the fastest way to order all windows bottom to tom and to render them to some image?

Does the win10 capture api work for invisible desktops?

Answer (score -1):

To answer the last question: No, the new win10 capture API doesnt't help.  For example the  program

https://github.com/robmikh/SimpleRecorder/tree/master/SimpleRecorder

cannot capture  a locked desktop nor can it capture sub windows.

The above is the elaborate version of:

GDI32Util.getScreenshot(handle)

with handle being the desktop window (doent work when locked) or some other window handle (works when locked, but misses the subwindows).

So the only option is to traverse all windows in z order from bottom to top.